# Whats the equivalent of tf.keras.Input() in pytorch?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

can someone tell me what the equivalent of tf.keras.Input() in pytorch is?

At the documentation it says, "Initiates a Keras Tensor", so does it just creates a new empty tensor?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There's no equivalent in PyTorch to the Keras' Input. All you have to do is pass on the inputs as a tensor to the PyTorch model.

For eg: If you're working with a Conv net:

```py
# Keras Code
input_image = Input(shape=(32,32,3)) # An input image of 32x32x3 (HxWxC)
feature = Conv2D(16, activation='relu', kernel_size=(3, 3))(input_image)
```

```py
# PyTorch code
input_tensor = torch.randn(1, 3, 32, 32) # An input tensor of shape BatchSizexChannelsxHeightxWidth
feature = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=16, kernel_size=(2, 2))(input_tensor)
```

If it is a normal Dense layer:

```py
# Keras
dense_input = Input(shape=(1,))
features = Dense(100)(dense_input)
```

```py
# PyTorch
input_tensor = torch.tensor([10]) # A 1x1 tensor with value 10
features = nn.Linear(1, 100)(input_tensor)
```

Answer (score 0):

I Create A custom Layer for check `Shape` , `Device` and `Dtype` of my `InputTensor` and i use it Like Tensorflow

```py
from torch.nn import Module

class Input(Module):

    def __init__(self, shape : tuple, device=torch.device('cpu'), dtype=torch.float32):
        
        super().__init__()

        self.shape = shape
        self.device = device
        self.dtype = dtype

    def forward(self, x):
        tensor_shape = tuple(x.shape[1:])

        if x.device != self.device:
            raise ValueError(f"Input tensor must be on device {self.device} but got device {x.device} instead")
        if x.dtype != self.dtype:
            raise ValueError(f"Input tensor must have data type {self.dtype} but got data type {x.dtype} instead")
        if tensor_shape != self.shape:
            raise ValueError(f"Input shape must be {self.shape} but got {tensor_shape} instead")
        
        return (x.to(self.device, self.dtype))
```

#### Utilisation With Subclassing Module

```py
from torch.nn import Module
from torch.nn import Linear
from torch.nn import ReLU, Sigmoid
from torch import Tensor

INPUT_FEATURES = X.shape[1]


class TestModel(Module):

      def __init__(self):

            super().__init__()

            self.InputLayer = Input(shape=(INPUT_FEATURES,))
            self.HiddenLayer = Linear(in_features=INPUT_FEATURES, 
                                      out_features=10)
            self.ReLU = ReLU()
            self.Sigmoid = Sigmoid()
            self.OutputLayer = Linear(in_features=10,
                                      out_features=1)
      
      def forward(self, x : Tensor):

            x = self.InputLayer(x)
            z = self.HiddenLayer(x)
            a = self.ReLU(z)
            z = self.OutputLayer(a)
            output = self.Sigmoid(z)

            return (output)
```

#### Utilisation With Sequential

```py
from torch.nn import Linear
from torch.nn import ReLU, Sigmoid
from torch.nn import Sequential

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
dtype = torch.float32

model = Sequential(
            Input(shape=(2,), device=device, dtype=dtype),
            Linear(2, 5),
            ReLU(),
            Linear(5, 1),
            Sigmoid()
)
```

I hope it helped ;)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).